# Synchronizing two child processes with semaphores in c

Tags: c, process, synchronization, fork, semaphore

I have to create a program that synchronizes two processes each printing only a single letter so that whenever we observe the output of the program, the difference between the amount of `"A"` and `"B"` is no greater than 2.

So this would be accepted:

```
BAABBAABBABA
```

this wouldn't be because it prints 4 B's and only 2 A's:

```
ABBABB
```

So for starters i decided to use the POSIX semaphores.
I created two semaphores , giving them all the permissions using the `sem_open`
Then i created two child processes and for each child process i open the semaphores i created as described in the man page for `sem_open` and manipulate them.

I don't think it's the logic of the `sem_post` and `sem_wait` that's at fault here, since the program seems to ignore them.

So my question is. What goes wrong?

Edit: I don't really need the solution to the problem. Some guidance alone would be much appreciated and welcoming as an answer. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int main(void){



  sem_t *semA = sem_open("/semA", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 0);   //Initialize semaphore(= 0) for process A
  sem_t *semB = sem_open("/semB", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 0);   //Initialize semaphore(= 0) for process B


  if (fork()){      // parent process
    if(fork()){}
    else{
      sem_t *childsemA = sem_open("/semA", 0);
      sem_t *childsemB = sem_open("/semB", 0);
      while(1){
        printf("A");
        sem_post(childsemB);
        sem_wait(childsemA);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    sem_t *childsemA = sem_open("/semA", 0);
    sem_t *childsemB = sem_open("/semB", 0);
    while(1){
      printf("B");    // child2 process
      sem_post(childsemA);
      sem_wait(childsemB);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong, semaphore are intended to be used with thread ( lightweight processes ), not with processes. Fork create a process that does not share parent's memory, so I don't think your parent's semaphore has interaction with your child's semaphore.

Comment: @mmeisson: No, OP is using [`sem_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) to open named semaphores; these are shared between processes.

Comment: OP, the standard C library buffers standard output. Add `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf()` to have the C library emit the letters to the actual standard output.

Comment: You don't need `childsemA` and `childsemB`, just use the `semA` and `semB` that was opened by the parent.

Comment: For strugglers, not to bog down your system, use `wait(0);` calls in parents

Comment: @NominalAnimal It seems that fflush was indeed the whole issue. Can't believe it was actually that simple. Thank you, i very much appreciate your help :)

Comment: If problem is about count of A or B, semaphores on printf will not help but should be on count of printfs.

Answer (score 2):

May i suggest you to use System V semaphores? This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#include "Semaphores.h"

#define SEM1_KEY (key_t)888
#define SEM2_KEY (key_t)1234

int sem1, sem2;


int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    sem1 = semget(SEM1_KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(sem1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nSEMGET Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sem2 = semget(SEM2_KEY, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(sem1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nSEMGET Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SEM_SET(sem1, 1);
    SEM_SET(sem2, 0);

    if((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError in fork()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {   
            SEM_WAIT(sem2);
            printf("%c", 'B');
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(1);
            SEM_POST(sem1);
        }
    }

    while(1)
    {
        SEM_WAIT(sem1);
        printf("%c", 'A');
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        SEM_POST(sem2);
    }

    wait(0);

    SEM_DEL(sem1);
    SEM_DEL(sem2);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And this is the header file Semaphores.h which includes the System V semaphores implementation:

```
#include <sys/sem.h>


union semun
{
    int val;

    struct semid_ds * buf;

    unsigned short * array;

};


int SEM_SET(int sem_id, int sem_val)
{
    union semun sem_union;

    sem_union.val = sem_val;

    return semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, sem_union);
}

int SEM_DEL(int sem_id)
{
    return semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID);
}

int SEM_WAIT(int sem_id)
{
    struct sembuf sem_buf;

    sem_buf.sem_num = 0;
    sem_buf.sem_op = -1;
    sem_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    return semop(sem_id, &sem_buf, 1);
}

int SEM_POST(int sem_id)
{
    struct sembuf sem_buf;

    sem_buf.sem_num = 0;
    sem_buf.sem_op = 1;
    sem_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    return semop(sem_id, &sem_buf, 1);
}
```

The result will be this:

> ABABABABABABABABA and so on

`fflush()` was probably the problem, but your code has some leaks, you need to understand what is a critical section, and you need to check for the return values of fork().

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it is a good answer, but it doesn't completely solve my original problem. You're forcing `A` and `B` to switch back and forth, while i'd like the code to  allow a letter to appear twice in a row based on race conditions.