# How to synchronize multiple processes in C?

Tags: c, unix, fork, ipc, semaphore

I have a car structure table which is in shared memory.
I run 10 fork() and wait until all the children are done to display the results. (The result is just their total time of each car, it's different because I am generating a random number for each car).

I am using a loop to generate numbers and store them in my totalTime variable. But I wouldn't want one process to end the loop to give access to the next. I want all processes to be in sync.

I think I should use a **semaphore** but after reading the documentation I don't know how to implement them.

Can someone help me please?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_CARS 10
#define MIN 25 // time generator
#define MAX 40

typedef struct {
    unsigned int totalTime;
} car;

car *shared_memory;

int drive(int i);
unsigned int generateNumber(void);
void display();

int main(void)
{
/***************************************************
*           Creating shared memory        *
****************************************************/
    int segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(car) * NUMBER_OF_CARS, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (segment_id == -1) {
        perror("shmget() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shared_memory = shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *) (-1)) {
        perror("shmat() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /**********************************************************
     *               Creation of child / cars              *
     **********************************************************/
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; ++i)
    {
        /********  échec du fork *********/
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork failed !");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /********  le fils *********/
        if(pid == 0) {
            drive(i);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        wait(NULL);
        display();
        sleep(1);
    }


    /********  Detach memory segments  *********/
    shmdt(shared_memory);
    /********  Delete shared memory  *********/
    shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

unsigned int timeMaxi = 5400;

int drive( int i ) {
    srand(time(NULL) + getpid());

    unsigned int number;

    // I want it to be executed by all processes at the same time!
    while ( shared_memory[i].totalTime <= timeMaxi )
    {
        number = generateNumber();
        shared_memory[i].totalTime += number;
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++){
        printf("Total %d : %d\n", i, shared_memory[i].totalTime);
    }
}

unsigned int generateNumber(void)
{
    return rand()%(MAX-MIN+1)+MIN;
}
```

Comment: If the children exit when they are done then `waitpid`   https://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid  
If you need to synchronise while they are still running a semaphore might work - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343144/synchronization-between-childs-and-parent-processes-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136645/synchronizing-two-child-processes-with-semaphores-in-c

Comment: What output are you getting, and what output do you expect?

Comment: I would like the parent printf () to set the value of totalTime but also the processes to be synchronized with each other.

Comment: Could someone help me write the code needed to synchronize the different processes ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, you do *not* need synchronization because each process is incrementing a different element of the array (indexed by `i`).

But, your placement of `wait(NULL)` (and `display`) will *force* all processes to be executed sequentially rather than in parallel.

So, remove the `sleep`. Move the `wait` into a loop of its own (*after* your `for` loop) and then do `display`:

```
while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
display();
```

In other words:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; ++i) {
    /********  échec du fork *********/
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /********  le fils *********/
    if (pid == 0) {
        drive(i);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
display();
```

---

If you're paranoid and wish to avoid any cache snooping/coherency issues, you could use `stdatomic.h` primitives:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

unsigned int timeMaxi = 5400;

int
drive(int i)
{
    srand(time(NULL) + getpid());

    unsigned int number;

    // I want it to be executed by all processes at the same time!
#if 0
    while (shared_memory[i].totalTime <= timeMaxi) {
        number = generateNumber();
        shared_memory[i].totalTime += number;
    }
#else
    while (1) {
        number = generateNumber();
        number += atomic_fetch_add(&shared_memory[i].totalTime,number);
        if (number > timeMaxi)
            break;
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thank you for your reply! I understand that in this program it is not necessary to use the semaphore. But I would like to use them to understand how it works. so if you can help me implement them. –
> bendour

Okay ... But, be careful what you wish for--you may actually get it :-)

Things would be easier with threads. Using the `stdatomic.h` primitives would allow more/better parallelism. We *could* create another shared memory area and use `sem_*` [posix] semaphores. But, since the original code used SysV shared memory areas, it seems fitting to use SysV semaphores for synchronization.

I created a version that uses SysV semaphores: `semget`, `semctl`. The actual mechanics of using these primitives is relatively easy/simple. See the `init`, `acquire`, and `release` functions in the sample code below.

However, I should point out that there is an issue with the processes "racing". That is, there is *no* guarantee of "fairness". When we use semaphores to sync things, there is an issue. Consider the following loop:

```
while (1) {
    // (1) lock semaphore
    // (2) do stuff ...
    // (3) unlock semaphore
}
```

The problem is that suppose we have *two* [or more] processes running the above loop.

If process A locks, does stuff, and unlocks, it can *monopolize* the lock. That is, after process A unlocks at step (3), it can win the race and immediately (re)lock at step (1) of the *next* iteration.

Other processes contending for the lock can be held off indefinitely because process A unlocks and immediately relocks the semaphore.

This can be hard to detect/measure. Interspersing debug `printf` calls will disturb the [real] timing.

A technique I've used in realtime/production code is to have a high speed "event trace queue". I've added debug code that supports that (the various `evt*` functions below). In lieu of debug `printf` calls, I've added calls that store away a history of the program execution (with timestamps), similar to what a H/W logic analyzer does (or Sun's `dtrace`).

When running these trace calls are *much* faster than `printf` calls. For example, on my system, adding a trace entry to the queue only takes 90 nanoseconds.

When the program/process completes, it dumps the trace queue to files that can be later post processed [with the `evtpost` script below].

After learning how to interpret the trace data, you'll [probably] notice that once a process gets the lock, it tends to be able to relock it and do more work at the expense of the other threads.

So, instead of getting a clean/balanced intersperal among the processes, the other processes are held off. This is known as thread/process "starvation".

Instead of getting a maximally parallel use of multiple processes running, the actual execution is much more "bursty" and/or sequential. This tends to defeat the whole purpose of having multiple processes in the first place.

That is why I [originally] suggested the "lockless" and `stdatomic.h` approaches. Those are but a few of the [known] techiques to alleviate the problem.

Anyway, here is the updated program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_CARS 10
#define MIN 25                          // time generator
#define MAX 40

#define MAXSEM      2                   // number of semaphores

typedef struct {
    unsigned int totalTime;
} car;

car *shared_memory;

int drive(void);
unsigned int generateNumber(void);
void display(void);

int carno;                              // current car number
int sem_id;                             // semaphore set ID
int acqrel;                             // acquire/release sequence number

typedef long long s64;
typedef s64 tsc_t;

tsc_t tsczero;

// tracing event
typedef struct {
    tsc_t evt_tsc;                      // event time
    const char *evt_name;               // event name
    int evt_carno;                      // car number
    s64 evt_val;                        // event value
} evt_t, *evt_p;

#define EVTMAX      10000
evt_t evtlist[EVTMAX];
int evtidx_enq;                         // enqueue index
int evtidx_deq;                         // dequeue index
FILE *evtxf;                            // evtdump stream

#if EVT
#define evtenq(_name,_val) \
    _evtenq(_name,_val)
#else
#define evtenq(_name,_val) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        fprintf(stderr,"%2.2d ",carno); \
        fprintf(stderr,_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

// tscget -- get hires timestamp
tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    tsc -= tsczero;

    return tsc;
}

// tscsec -- convert timestamp to fractional seconds
double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

// evtinc -- increment queue index with wrap
int
evtinc(int idx)
{

    idx += 1;
    idx %= EVTMAX;

    return idx;
}

// _evtenq -- enqueue trace event
evt_p
_evtenq(const char *name,s64 val)
{
    int enqcur = evtidx_enq;
    int enqnext = evtinc(enqcur);
    evt_p evt;

    // pop element off queue to make room if queue is full
    if (enqnext == evtidx_deq)
        evtidx_deq = evtinc(evtidx_deq);

    evt = &evtlist[enqcur];
    evtidx_enq = enqnext;

    evt->evt_tsc = tscget();

    evt->evt_name = name;
    evt->evt_carno = carno;

    evt->evt_val = val;

    return evt;
}

// evtdeq -- dequeue trace event
evt_p
evtdeq(void)
{
    evt_p evt;

    do {
        // bug out on empty queue
        if (evtidx_deq == evtidx_enq) {
            evt = NULL;
            break;
        }

        evt = &evtlist[evtidx_deq];
        evtidx_deq = evtinc(evtidx_deq);
    } while (0);

    return evt;
}

// evtdump -- dump out trace queue
void
evtdump(void)
{
    FILE *xf;
    int openflg;
    char file [100];
    evt_p evt;

    xf = evtxf;
    openflg = (xf == NULL);
    if (openflg) {
        sprintf(file,"evtdump_%2.2d",carno);
        xf = fopen(file,"w");
    }

    flock(fileno(xf),LOCK_EX);

    while (1) {
        evt = evtdeq();
        if (evt == NULL)
            break;

        fprintf(xf,"[%.9f/%2.2d] %s %lld\n",
            tscsec(evt->evt_tsc),evt->evt_carno,evt->evt_name,evt->evt_val);
    }

    fflush(xf);
    flock(fileno(xf),LOCK_UN);

    if (openflg)
        fclose(xf);
}

// init -- initialize semaphore set
void
init(void)
{
    int err;
    int val;

    sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, MAXSEM, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (sem_id == -1) {
        perror("shmget() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int semnum = 0;  semnum < MAXSEM;  ++semnum) {
        // get the old value
        err = semctl(sem_id,semnum,GETVAL,NULL);
        printf("init: semnum=%d err=%d\n",semnum,err);

        // set initial value (otherwise, we will hang in acquire)
        val = 1;
        err = semctl(sem_id,semnum,SETVAL,val);

        // show the new value
        err = semctl(sem_id,semnum,GETVAL,NULL);
        printf("init: semnum=%d err=%d\n",semnum,err);
    }
}

// acquire -- acquire the semaphore
void
acquire(int semnum)
{
    struct sembuf sop;
    int err;

    ++acqrel;

    sop.sem_num = semnum;
    sop.sem_op = -1;
    sop.sem_flg = 0;

    evtenq("acquire/BEG",acqrel);
    err = semop(sem_id,&sop,1);
    if (err < 0)
        err = errno;
    evtenq("acquire/END",acqrel);

    if (err)
        sysfault("acquire: fault semnum=%d -- %s\n",semnum,strerror(err));
}

// release -- release the semaphore
void
release(int semnum)
{
    struct sembuf sop;
    int err;

    sop.sem_num = semnum;
    sop.sem_op = 1;
    sop.sem_flg = 0;

    evtenq("release/BEG",acqrel);
    err = semop(sem_id,&sop,1);
    if (err < 0)
        err = errno;
    evtenq("release/END",acqrel);

    if (err)
        sysfault("acquire: fault semnum=%d -- %s\n",semnum,strerror(err));
}

void
sighdr(int signo)
{

    evtdump();
    exit(9);
}

int
main(void)
{

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    setlinebuf(stderr);

    tsc_t tsc = tscget();
#if 0
    srand(tsc);
#endif
    tsczero = tsc;

    signal(SIGINT,sighdr);

    init();

#if 0
    evtxf = fopen("evtdump","w");
#endif

    // Creating shared memory
    int segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(car) * NUMBER_OF_CARS,
        0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (segment_id == -1) {
        perror("shmget() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shared_memory = shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *) (-1)) {
        perror("shmat() failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /**********************************************************
     *               Creation of child / cars              *
     **********************************************************/
    for (carno = 0; carno < NUMBER_OF_CARS; ++carno) {
        /********  échec du fork *********/
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork failed !");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /********  le fils *********/
        if (pid == 0) {
            drive();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

#if 0
        wait(NULL);
        display();
        sleep(1);
#endif
    }

#if 1
    while (wait(NULL) >= 0);
    display();
#endif

    /********  Detach memory segments  *********/
    shmdt(shared_memory);
    /********  Delete shared memory  *********/
    shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    // delete semaphores
    for (int semno = 0;  semno < MAXSEM;  ++semno)
        semctl(sem_id, semno, IPC_RMID);

    if (evtxf != NULL)
        fclose(evtxf);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

unsigned int timeMaxi = 5400;

int
drive(void)
{
#if 1
    srand(tscget() + tsczero + getpid());
#endif

    unsigned int number;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx <= 10;  ++idx)
        evtenq("drive/TEST",idx);

    car *car = &shared_memory[carno];

    // I want it to be executed by all processes at the same time!

    // non-synced version
#if 0
    while (car->totalTime <= timeMaxi) {
        number = generateNumber();
        car->totalTime += number;
    }
#endif

    // atomic primitive version
#if 0
    while (1) {
        number = generateNumber();
        number += atomic_fetch_add(&car->totalTime,number);
        if (number > timeMaxi)
            break;
    }
#endif

    // acquire/release semaphore version
#if 1
    while (1) {
        acquire(0);

        if (car->totalTime > timeMaxi) {
            release(0);
            break;
        }

        number = generateNumber();
        car->totalTime += number;

        release(0);
    }
#endif

    evtdump();
    exit(0);

    return 0;
}

void
display(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++) {
        printf("Total %d : %d\n", i, shared_memory[i].totalTime);
    }
}

unsigned int
generateNumber(void)
{
    return rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1) + MIN;
}
```

When compiled with `-DEVT`, the trace event mechanism is enabled. It will store the trace data in some `evtdump_*` files.

Here is a [perl] script that can post process/merge these files. Its output allows us to see how each process interacts timewise:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# sysvsem/evtpost -- post process evtdump files

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    $xfile = shift(@argv);
    $xfile //= "sysvsem";

    @tails = dirload(".");
    foreach $tail (@tails) {
        next unless ($tail =~ /^evtdump/);
        open($xfsrc,"<$tail");

        while ($bf = <$xfsrc>) {
            chomp($bf);
            push(@evt,$bf);
        }

        close($xfsrc);
    }

    @evt = sort(evtsort @evt);

    foreach $evt (@evt) {
        print($evt,"\n");
    }
}

sub evtsort
{
    my($lhs,$rhs);
    my($cmpflg);

    $lhs = _evtsort($a);
    $rhs = _evtsort($b);

    $cmpflg = $lhs <=> $rhs;

    $cmpflg;
}

sub _evtsort
{
    my($bf) = @_;
    my($av);
    my($val);

    ($av) = split(" ",$bf);

    if ($av =~ s/^\[//) {
        $av =~ s/\]$//;
        ($val) = split("/",$av);
    }

    sysfault("_evtsort: bf='%s'\n",$bf)
        unless (defined($val));

    $val;
}

sub dirload
{
    my($dir) = @_;
    my($xfdir);
    my($tail);
    my(@tails);

    opendir($xfdir,$dir);

    while ($tail = readdir($xfdir)) {
        next if ($tail eq ".");
        next if ($tail eq "..");
        push(@tails,$tail);
    }

    closedir($xfdir);

    @tails = sort(@tails);

    @tails;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I understand that in this program it is not necessary to use the semaphore. But I would like to use them to understand how it works. so if you can help me implement them.