# Recursive logging in C (i.e. logging the logging functions)

Tags: c, recursion, logging

I have a custom logging framework in my C program, with a Log() function. I understand that rule #2 or 3 of including logging is 'do not reinvent the wheel', but I cannot overcome the desire to avoid the overhead of adding dependencies on some external library or service.

I want to log stuff in my logging functions and am coming up with situations where it becomes deeply recursive. Are there any guides or techniques out there that would help me resolve this? Ideally platform and external library/service independent.

I spent the required hour or so searching for an answer, but nothing particularly useful came up. This probably means I am missing some fundamental knowledge.

I added detection of recursion, with logging to temporary buffers then transfer of those buffers to the log later, but after some thought, this just pushes the problem down a level, and will not fundamentaly remove the problem.

I am working in Windows, and I currently have a second LogErr() function that I use in my logging functions that pops up a window with the log message and returns, but this doesn't store the log, and can be hugely annoying...

Not sure how much it helps, but here is the code for Log(), with quite a lot of stuff snipped. I would like to replace LogErr() with Log(). I use an event structure to store the log data, as I also use the Log() function to transfer some other data, but I think that is irrelevant here...

```
void Log(char Severity, char* str, ...)
{

    DWORD ThreadID;
    va_list args;
    struct Event Event;
    unsigned long long Time;
    char ExpandedString[MAX_STR_LEN], err = FALSE;

    // Get this early so we get the best log timestamp
    Time = Timestamp();

    // Create the log message string
    va_start(args, str);
    vsnprintf_s(ExpandedString, MAX_STR_LEN, MAX_STR_LEN, str, args);
    va_end(args);

    ThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();

    // Create the event container for putting the log data into
    // 
    if (CreateNNEvent(&Event) == FALSE)
    {
        LogErr("Could not create event structure to record thread ID %lu log: [%d][%llu] %s", ThreadID, Severity, Time, ExpandedString);
        return;
    }
    // Below here we must now destroy this event before returning

    Event.WDB.Time = Time;
    Event.Code = EC_LOG;
    Event.Value.DataType = DT_STR;
```

.
.
.

Comment: Having `Log()` when [`log()` is a well-known function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log) is going to seem strange.

Comment: Can you give some code for context here showing the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe the log function can just print to `stderr`.

Comment: I want to have a log window in the program where I can view and filter, etc. the logs. So I really need them in some internal buffer or file I think

Comment: I've done exactly what you're trying to do in my own code for many years. I posted a limited version on SO in my answer: [How to synchronize multiple processes in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817970/5382650) AFAICT, the main difference is that my "event" struct isn't on the stack but is part of a ring queue. You've shown the code that creates your event struct, but not how/where you're storing it (for later replay). So, what is your question?

Comment: Recursive logging?  What's the point? What are you going to do?  Log errors in your logging? If the log functionality is broken, it's broken and recursively logging failures never ends, in which case you either give up or crash.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Maybe my code example is not the best. The logs are actually written to buffers, and if the buffer is in the process of being written to, a further call to write to the buffer will fail. This is not really an error, so I want to try and save that second log. But maybe if I identify the real logging errors (Such as in the code I posted) and just use my LogErr() popup for those, and implement some wait loop for the other situations, I can eliminate the recursion black hole I am seeing...

Comment: Based on my own experience, I agree 100% with Andrew's comment. I've never found a use for recursive logging. I'm not even sure how one can make _logging_ recursive in any meaningful way. Or, _exactly_ what you mean by the term. Good logging should be as minimal, lightweight, atomic, and fast as possible.

Comment: @CraigEstey I was trying to keep it simple and not focus on the Event part. That is actually there for recording and transferring more complex progress data between threads in the program. But as I already have a bunch of functions to manage info in this structure, I chose to use it for my logging also. My question is much simpler - just how you might manage calls to Log() from within Log() itself without getting into some recursion black hole. Maybe separating logging errors (which raise the recursion issue) from parallel calls (See my comment above) might be my solution.

Comment: Your issue may be that you are trying to conflate two different things. I'm not sure what you mean by _**progress** data between threads_ If you mean request blocks in work queues, my take on that: [In C, is storing data in local variables in threads akin to creating a local copy? AKA Does this Threadpool synchronization make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762865/5382650)) Note that I do logging/tracing within the functions that send/receive interthread messages (e.g. `dbgprt`). In my real code, `dbgprt` would use the event ring queue of my other answer