# Unable to read value from gpio set as input

Tags: c, embedded, gpio, cortex-m, imx7

I am working on a custom board with two IMX7ULP. The thing I'm trying to do seems quite simple, the A7 from one IMX7ULP send a signal to the M4 of the other IMX7ULP, just an electrical signal, one of the pin of the A7 as output, one of the pin of the M4 as input (PTA16), no special communication protocol. We manage to set the pin of the A7 as an output (even checked with the multimeter) and we do what seems correct to set the pin as an input but nothing is read and it keeps returning me a value of 0.

The code I made looks like this

```
#define GPIO_HEARTBEAT_READ 16U

 gpio_pin_config_t digitalInput = { //set as input
        kGPIO_DigitalInput,
    };

    /* Init board hardware. */
    BOARD_InitPins();
    BOARD_BootClockRUN();
    BOARD_InitDebugConsole();
    CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_Rgpio2p0);

    
    /* Init input GPIO. */
    GPIO_PinInit(GPIOA, GPIO_HEARTBEAT_READ, &digitalInput);

    int value = GPIO_PinRead(GPIOA, GPIO_HEARTBEAT_READ);
    PRINTF("Value of HEARTBEAT_READ : %d\n", value);
    PRINTF("Value of register of heartbeat : %x\n", READ_reg());
```

and value is set as 0 while the register read 0x10100 which is what I am expecting for a pin set as input.

I also checked the IOMUXC mode to make sure it is correctly set as GPIO :

```
void BOARD_InitPins(void) {    
    IOMUXC_SetPinMux(IOMUXC_PTA16_PTA16, 0U);
}
```

I even tried forcing it in pull-down to create a difference in potential at the pin but nothing changed. I'm currently running out of ideas, is there something I'm missing ? Is it more a hardware problem than software (if it's the case, I apologize and I'll be looking somewhere else)

Thank you in advance

Edit : someone asked for a code where they blinked the LED, which was given by default and I changed it to try taking an input instead :

```
#define LED_GPIO_PIN 20U

int main(void)
{

    gpio_pin_config_t digitalOutput = {  //allows for setting the pin as an output
        kGPIO_DigitalOutput,
        0,
    };

    /* Init board hardware. */
    BOARD_InitPins();
    BOARD_BootClockRUN();
    //BOARD_InitDebugConsole();
    CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_Rgpio2p0);

    
    /* Init output LED GPIO. */
    GPIO_PinInit(GPIOA, LED_GPIO_PIN, &digitalOutput);
    GPIO_PortSet(GPIOA, 1u << LED_GPIO_PIN);    

    while(1) {
        delay(10000);
        GPIO_PortToggle(GPIOA, 1u << LED_GPIO_PIN);
    }
}
```

We were also able to set the M4 pin as output and the A7 pin as input and to receive a signal on the A7

Last edit : I don't why but I managed to get the pin info using interrupts and NVIC IRQ Handler. Still no value read with GPIO_PinRead though. Thank you for the comments, it helped.

Comment: Problems like this are most often related to routing/mux registers indeed, but you already knew that. I don't know this particular hardware so I'm of no help there. Maybe there's an app note or code example for blinking a LED? Then you could tweak it to taking an input instead.

Comment: @Lundin there is indeed a code for blinking a LED and I used it to try taking an input instead. I'll add it in the edited post but as you'll see, they declare it as output and toggle it with GPIO_PinToggle.

Comment: Hmm very similar, I guess you already based your code on it :) Well it could of course also be a hw problem, if you are using some evaluation board or the like. They made GPIO so dang needlessly complicated on all modern MCUs...

Comment: You have a _custom_ board? Can you verify the trace from the A7 to the M4 pin? You've got _two_ `IMX7ULP`. What about trying A7 to M4 on a _single_ chip first? Can you get two SDK boards (e.g.) https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/iMX7ULP_uCOM_Board_Flyer.pdf and try things there? When trying to debug S/W while doing custom H/W bringup, I sometimes like to use an SDK board to try to separate S/W issues from H/W issues.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes I have a custom board, it's suppose to be used as an OBC for a student project. We did verify the trace from the A7 to the M4 pin (I can set the pin of the M4 as output and the pin of the A7 as input and receive the signal). The problem of testing on one chip is that there is no GPIO connection between the two (just the one to power the A7). Unfortunately we only have one SDK board and not enough time to order a second one, but I would have totally done this if possible.

Comment: How are you getting debug data in/out (e.g. UART)? I add debug `printf` (via a macro that hooks on `-DDEBUG` (e.g.)). Also, I use a ring buffer of trace "events". For an example, see my answer: [How to synchronize multiple processes in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817970/5382650) and look at the `evt*` stuff. Got an oscilloscope and/or logic analyzer?